# heroku deployment error with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, heroku, deployment, sinatra-activerecord

I'm trying to deploy my web-app with heroku but I'm having few problems.
My app is built using sinatra and postgresql... 
When I try to deploy, apparently heroku doesn't read my database, I tried with

```
   heroku pg:psql
```

but it didn't work.

This is the error message I'm getting

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w0tu.png)

Answer (score 0):

looks your database is not set properly. Create database first then get it's url and set it in environments.rb file for more information you can follow [this](http://mherman.org/blog/2013/06/08/designing-with-class-sinatra-plus-postgresql-plus-heroku/#.V2JDUtx96xU) blog